# What is the type I should give to the column in My SQL where I have list of URLs to my images

Tags: mysql

it is my first experience with DB and therefore I'm kinda lost since I do not know much about it, so please go easy on me.

I am creating a table in MySQL where one of the columns will hold full path URLs to the images (one per line) like the following `http://cdn.example.com/images/image1.png`
My question is, what type should I give to this column, what MIME type, what Browser transformation and at last Transformation options?

So what I am trying to achieve is, when image is requested it should create the following

`<img src="http://cdn.example.com/images/image1.png" width="150" Height="200" alt="Image Title">`

I am also planning on creating another column for image width, image height and for alt.

can you please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the length of the URL you'll be holding but I'd use `varchar(255)` for the column type.

I've never had to worry about the MIME types. 99.999% of the time you will ignore them and just leave them empty.

Hope this helps you

Comment: If you need to do anything with MIME types, you'll need to handle that in your web app.  You could store that info in another column or something if you're going to be storing various types of image and want to explicitly set the MIME type.

Comment: @ChrisDisley Thanks for your comment, I will skip MIME, since it wont be used anywhere. It was just a question for me to understand what it was and where it is necessary or not, but since it isn't in my case I would just ignore it completely.

Answer (score 0):

if you are storing just the url and not the full tag varchar 255 should be enough. If you trim out the extra http:// , you save 7 characters

Comment: Thanks for you response, I have another question, what if I store <img src="http://cdn.example.com/images/image1.png" width="150" Height="200" alt="Image Title"> instead of storing just URL, than I wont need to create another columns for Width, Height and Alt? Do you think is it OK to do it like this?

Comment: it all depends on the scenario but I would say the full tag is more likely to end up over 255 limit. I would either put them in another column or not specify a width (auto sets to correct size). if they are all the same size, you can set the size in the script. You might even trim it even further if all files are in the same directory by storing only the image name.

Comment: I think I will only store the name of the image and leave a path for PHP on the page, but image size is important for validation and plus isn't the same for all images so I'd rather place in another column. Thanks, all suggestions are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use TEXT instead of varchar and not worry about the length restriction of varchar

- remember to enforce length restriction at your application program level rather than at the db level .. e.g. dont allow URLs larger than 500 characters
- VARCHAR access is faster than TEXT ... so depending on performance requirement you may have to make a trade-off here